# Serialization Java Mail

Tags: java, object, serialization, byte, blob

I am writing a mail service based on the **JakartaMail** Java library. There is a need to receive the contents of the message. To do this, I use **msg.getContent()**, which returns the **Object** type.
Having studied the issue in detail, I came to the conclusion that there is no universal way to disassemble the content of the message. You can only check for belonging to one of the types. Therefore, it would be advantageous for me to serialize the **Object** type, **which returns the getContent** **method** completely, **the problem is that it is not serializable**. I will be grateful for your help

```
blic Blob mapDtoToEntity(Message msg) throws Exception {

        Blob blob = new Blob();
        Object object = msg.getContent(); // получаем содержимое сообщения

        // создаем два потока baos - базовый класс для реализации выходного потока,
        // в котором данные записываются в массив байтов
        // ois - преобразует объекты в байты

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try (ObjectOutputStream ois = new ObjectOutputStream(baos)) {
            ois.writeObject(object);
            byte[] arrayByteObject = baos.toByteArray();
            blob.setObject(arrayByteObject);
        }
            baos.close(); //закрываем поток

            return blob;

    }}
```

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMultipart
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1197)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:354)
    at com.axsoft.mail.utils.impl.BlobMappingUtils.mapDtoToEntity(BlobMappingUtils.java:26)
    at com.axsoft.mail.services.Service.saveMessageRepos(Service.java:51)
    at com.axsoft.mail.MailApplication.run(MailApplication.java:26)
    a org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:767)
```

Comment: It is probably a good thing that object serialization doesn't work.  Saving email content as serialized objects is liable to lead to unexpected version mismatches when you update your code dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class `MimeMessage` has method `writeTo(OutputStream)` which lets you write out the entire message, including its headers. It has a constructor `MimeMessage(Session, InputStream)` that lets you create a message from a previously serialized message.

If you don't want to save the entire message but only its body, you can use `getDataHandler().writeTo(outputStream)` instead.